# How to make summary table of with respect to data in tables in access

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

This site is really good and I have got many help from u all.. So thank u for your help.

Now I have doubt. I have 3 tables called `b1,b2,b3` in access having the same field but different data.

I want to make summary of the data in it in single table, like in `b1` there is cable1 with 4m length, and in `b3` there is cable1 with 8 m length..so in summary it should show cable 1 with 8+4 m length.

Any idea how to do it? Does union query help in this situation?

Comment: A simple join should suffice, but if you can show the table structure and sample data we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Purely based on your descriptioin and with no detail of your tables I would assume you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT [CableType],
convert(nvarchar(5),B1.[Length]) + 'm +' + convert(nvarchar(5),B2.[Length])
+ 'm +' + convert(nvarchar(5),B3.[Length]) + 'm' as [Length]
FROM [B1]
join [B2] on [B1].[ID] = [B2].[ID]
join [B3] on [B1].[ID] = [B3].[ID]
```

I guess you have a column which holds the "Cable 1" description somewhere, also assuming you have an identifying column of some kind and your Lengths are stored as a number of some kind. This example would assume you always populate all 3 tables.